# Report that shows when HTML emails were opened

Tags: email, reporting

How can I create a report that shows when HTML emails were last opened.  I can see this information when looking at a contact's past history.  I have run the HTML Email Status report.  It lists a very small number of emails that were sent and the date they were last opened.  How can I get a complete list of emails sent and when they were last opened.  I am not using Eistein Activity Capture.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML Email Status Report [only shows messages that were sent by the running user](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000003665&language=en_US). The help article also mentions:

> To make the HTML Email Status report available to others
>
> 1. Add your HTML Email Status report to a Salesforce.com Dashboard.
> 2. Set 'View Dashboard As' to the User that sent the email.
> 3. Save the dashboard.

There's no way to get all status from all users in a single report or view.